# Navigation bar getting invisible on Safari, Uc browser but working on Firefox and Android

Tags: html

My website's nav bar is working fine on Firefox and Chrome but on Safari and UC nav bar getting invisible when navigated to other page. Let's say you open my website "rockface.000webhostapp.com" nav bar will be visible at that time but when you go to Products-> Custom built diamond tools nav bar becomes invisible on UC and Safari. If anyone could help me in sorting out the reason would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

First before start did you check the css code with vaildators ? and remember that you must add -webkit- to every code like this :

```js
function myTry(x) {
document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = x;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
/* Transition for Safari & Mozilla & IE */
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s;
/* Normal transition */
transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar:hover {
background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
Hover Me !
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="myTry('green')"> Green </button>
<button onclick="myTry('red')"> Red </button>
<button onclick="myTry('blue')"> Blue </button>
<button onclick="myTry('white')"> White </button>
<button onclick="myTry('')"> Origin ( No Background ) </button>
```

If you try this example in every browser it will works fine but if you remove
-webkit- and -moz- from stylesheet (CSS) you will got no transition !